# Delete files with almost similar name with a Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I got a list of photos with names that look like this:

```
/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-1.jpg
/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59.jpg
/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54-1.jpg
/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54.jpg
[...]
```

I am trying to delete all the photos whose names are "similar". What I am trying to do is some kind of pattern matching.

How can I find out if the first n characters are the same for two strings?

Comment: To find identical files, you should compare the content, not the name.

Comment: unfortunately they have different hash values ... this has been my first approach

Comment: This look like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Wouldn't it be easier to traverse the directory and for each file `basename.jpg`, check if there is a `basename-1.jpg` (or `-2`, `-3`) and delete the latter?

Comment: @stefan - this sounds like a nice approach! and thanks for the article on the xy problem! i will give it a try tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

Reading between the lines, it appears that you have determined that, in

```
arr = [
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-1.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-2.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-21.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54-2.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-32.jpg',
  '/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.56-1.jpg'
]
```

the files `arr[0,3]`are the same, because the file names differ only by the optional inclusion of a hyphen, followed by one or more digits, immmediately prior to `".jpg"`, and you want to delete all but one file in the group (i.e. delete two of the three files). Moreover, if one file in the group does not contain the optional hyphen followed by one or more digits prior to `'.jpg"`, that file--the "base file"--is the one that is not to be deleted. Similarly, all but one file of the group `[arr[3], arr[6]]` and of the group `arr[4,2]` are to be deleted. The group `[arr[7]]` contains only one file, so no file from that group is to be deleted.

**Code**

You can do that by using the regular expression

```
r = /
    \A           # match beginning of string
    .+?          # match one or more of any character, lazily
    (?=          # begin a positive lookahead
      (?:-\d+)?  # optionally (?) match hypen, one or more digits, in a non-capture group 
      \.jpg\z    # match ".jpg" followed by end of string
    )            # end positive lookahead
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

in conjunction with instance methods [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values), [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D), and the class method [File::#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-delete):

```
arr.group_by { |f| f[r] }.values.flat_map { |a| a-[a.max] }.each { |f| File.delete(f) }
```

**Explanation**

The steps follow.

```
h = arr.group_by { |f| f[r] }
  #=> {"/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59"=>
  #      ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-1.jpg",
  #       "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59.jpg",
  #       "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-2.jpg"],
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55"=>
  #      ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-21.jpg",
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-32.jpg"],
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54"=>
  #      ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54-2.jpg",
  #       "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54.jpg"],
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.56"=>
  #      ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.56-1.jpg"]} 
v = h.values
  #=> [["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-1.jpg",
  #     "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59.jpg",
  #     "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-2.jpg"],
  #    ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54-2.jpg",
  #     "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54.jpg"],
  #    ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-21.jpg",
  #     "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-32.jpg"],
  #    ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.56-1.jpg"]]
b = v.flat_map { |a| a-[a.max] }
  #=> ["/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-1.jpg",
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.05.59-2.jpg",
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.55-21.jpg",
  #    "/Users/foo/Desktop/argentinien-chile 2/2009-12-21 17.16.54-2.jpg"]
```

Note that, because `"." > "-" #=> true`, if a group contains a "base file", it will be `a.max`; hence, the file that is not deleted.

```
b.each { |f| File.delete(f) }
```

Comment: That would delete all files ending with `-n.jpg`, regardless of whether there is a "base" file without `-n`.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I made the lazy and unstated assumption that each group would have a "base" file. I did an edit to relax that assumption. Do you see any simplifications I could make?

Comment: If files without a "base file" should be kept (e.g. both, `55-21.jpg` and `55-32.jpg`), you could also `group_by { |f| f.gsub(/-\d+(?=\.jpg\z)/, '') }` and then select all files that are not equal to their respective key.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. In the case you mention you could also construct an array `base` of base files, then step through `arr-base`, deleting each file whose "base file" is in `base`.

Comment: thank the both of you! the explanation is awesome btw! thank you for putting that much effort into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 'aabbccdd'
b = 'aabbrrgg'
n = 4
a[0...n] == b[0...n]
# or
a[0,n] == b[0,n]
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is, that i need to know a in order to say that it equates to b. but then i could just do it by hand

Comment: You asked "How can I find out if the first n characters are the same for two strings?". This is exactly what you wanted. If you want something else, you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: this is why every question has a body ;) - but i will rephrase to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find out if the first n characters are the same for two
>   strings?

By the context, what it seems you are really asking is "find out how many characters are the same at the beginning for two strings?" If that's the case:

```
s1 = "hello there!"
s2 = "helloween"
s1.chars.zip(s2.chars).take_while { |c1, c2| c1 == c2 }.count
#=> 5
```

Comment: I want to delete all duplicate photos in a directory. And I can see that they are duplicates when their names are the same except for the last party with '-1'. sorry for not being clear on that.